# Passing an array's item as argument to the function in angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular2 app I have roughly this app.component.ts:

```
...
export class AppComponent {
    // themes array
    readonly themes = ['assets/default-theme.css', 'assets/test-theme.css', ...];

    // theme setter
    setTheme(href: string) {
        setThemeLinkHref(href);
        console.log('Theme has been changed to: ' + href);
    }
    ...
}
```

And I have this code in template (app.component.html):

```
...
<button (click)="setTheme(themes[0])">Default</button>
...
```

This way I get '**undefined**' theme's href in log:

```
Theme has been changed to: undefined
```

**How to pass one certain array's item to function as argument?**

Answer (score 2):

Without duplicating code, you can use **`ngFor`** as below,

```
 <button mat-menu-item  *ngFor="let theme of themes" (click)="setTheme(theme)"> {{theme.name}}</button>
```

Also change your themes array as follows without **`readonly`** accessifier,

```
themes = [ {'theme':'assets/default-theme.css','name':'Default', {'theme':'assets/test-theme.css','name':'Test'}];
```

Comment: This answer doesn't target OPs problem.

Comment: why not? providing better way is always better answer

Comment: OP asks why he gets undefined when trying to set theme, not how to improve the DOM. Besides, you would need to elaborate your answer furthermore. He uses a label for each button which needs to be displayed and needs to trigger an action.

Comment: Sorry Sajeetharan, I knew how to iterate items with *ngFor. I changed the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `readonly` modifier and it seems to work.